# How to Iterate over entire android listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview where user choose how much for each item he wants, so I need to iterate over each row to get the name (Ovo, Presunto, Queijo, etc), the quantity (the number between the "+" and "-" buttons) and the price. This is already working fine, but I have the following problem: If you look at the bottom of the listview you can know that there are more items, in this picture there are 9 items, but there are 15, and if the user scrolls I will can not iterate over the "hidden" items of listview.

[image: My listview]

Today I have this code, where I try iterate over the elements of listview:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
        v = listView.getChildAt(i);
        if(v != null){
            value = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.edOptionValue);
            nome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvOptionName);
            tvPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            String price = tvPrice.getText().toString();

            //more code here
    }
}
```

listView.getCount() gets the correct number of items (15 items), but when i==10 listView.getChildAt(i) is getting null.

Is there some way to iterate over all items of a listview, incluing the "hidden" elements ?

Comment: iterate on the dataset you submitted to the adapter

Comment: The dataset do not include the properties that I need (price, quantity). I need to get this values from the listview.

Comment: Why someone give a downvote before to understand what am I needing !? Or at least give any explanations

Comment: *The dataset do not include the properties that I need (price, quantity).*, you may have some misunderstanding of how this thing should work

Comment: The listview is used to the user set how much of "Ovo" or "Maionese" or "Cheddar" the user wants. I will only know this values if I read the value inserted in the listview item. This is why I wrote "The dataset do not include the properties that I need (price, quantity)"

Comment: Whatever you're doing to "insert" data into the `ListView` should be updating the dataset, not just the `View`s in the `ListView`.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. I found that is impossible to get invisible childs of listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not iterate the list views, instead you should keep all that data (price/quantity) in a list and iterate over that if you really need to do that. That list can be used to populate the `ListView` as well.